# Is it possible (in sed) to remove a newline character only when preceding character isn't a dot?

Tags: regex, sed

I define a paragraph as a text(which can include '.' in the middle) which ends with a '.' and followed by a '\n'. For example, here are 2 paragraphs:

```
first
paragraph.
second paragraph.
```

I want this text to be transformed as

```
first paragraph.
second paragraph.
```

I tried this

```
sed 's/\([^\n\.]\)\(\n\)/\1 /g' file.txt
```

but it didn't affect an output, though it seemed to be an obvious solution after I learned about grouping matches in pattern space and returning certain group in hold space.
My idea was to substitute all '\n' which are not following a '.' with a single space. I've looked up some one-line scripts that convert unix format newline characters to dos newlines, but it didn't solve my problem.
Important thing is I want to leave all '\n' that go after '.', so simple 's/\n/ /g' won't work for me.

I'm just interested if it even possible to do it with exactly sed? I would appreciate if anyone would point me in what direction i should learn about sed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sed can do it, but you'll need an advanced sed command, Are you familiar with branching or the hold space?

Comment: `sed` can do it but it is not the best tool for doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show it's possible with sed but I'd suggest to use other tools (shell, awk, python, ...) for this. It's not easy to do logic with sed.

```
[STEP 101] $ cat file
this
is the
1st paragraph.
this is the
2nd paragraph.
this is the 3rd paragraph.
this is the
4th paragraph?
[STEP 102] $ sed -e :go -e '$q;N;/[.]\n/{P;D;};s/\n/ /;bgo' file
this is the 1st paragraph.
this is the 2nd paragraph.
this is the 3rd paragraph.
this is the 4th paragraph?
[STEP 103] $
```

To deal with blank lines:

```
[STEP 104] $ cat file
this is the


1st paragraph.

this is the

2nd paragraph.

this is the 3rd paragraph.
this is the

4th paragraph?
[STEP 105] $ sed -e :go -e '$q;N;/[.]\n/{P;D;};s/^\n//;s/[ ]*\n[ ]*/ /;bgo' file
this is the 1st paragraph.
this is the 2nd paragraph.
this is the 3rd paragraph.
this is the 4th paragraph?
[STEP 106] $
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `sed` but you have to fold lines and use label. `awk` fits better to this task. Also it is good to add a space after lines without an ending dot.

```
awk '{s=($0~/\.$/)? "\n": " "; printf $0 s}' file
```